# Create Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this short sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNBxrr)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

asda

[link exampe](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

do not understand why the W3Schools example is different from mine.

I put virtually the same code and have implemented bootstrap library.

Can you please tell me what the problem is and what example shows the two different?

Comment: The codepen you provided works for me when you hover over the link.

Comment: yes but the design is different between the two examples

Comment: You haven't added bootstrap jQuery plugin

Comment: @JohnSmith so you want tool tip in right but not top?

Comment: @Leothelion want a tooltip as the W3Schools

Comment: @JohnSmith w3Schools have 2 type of..one is showing on page and second is in example..give me 1 min plz

Comment: @John bootrstrap.min.js?

Comment: @JohnSmith like this http://www.bootply.com/W3p5kDDylv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using this code to attain that result unlike your one line of code

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</a>
</div>
<script>$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The important thing to note is this part

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

AND this API:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So I used their and found out that when you remove the above javascript code the result is same as yours. So add the above script element to your code and link **the bootstrap js library** and **Bootstrap-combined.css**.

To get the tooltip above the text use this code:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
```

Doing so will give you the same result as there

For more reference use this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

[image: Proof that it is working]

Comment: @Leothelion  Well it wasn't there when I checked it

Comment: M not sure why op marked this as answer while its not what op wants.. He din even mentioned working fiddle, neither for right as tooltip was on top already..strange

Comment: @Leothelion please try the same code on any other [ide online](http://codepen.io/animenon/pen/EKpZzE).

Comment: bootstrap-combined.min.css this was missing. M not sure how to edit pen so i created fiddle..

Comment: @AniMenon i used the w3schools text editor it was working there 
 aslo i tried it locally there also I found out that it was working

Comment: @Rasik I think its a problem with few of the ides. But I still don't know [why](http://jsfiddle.net/ani1/14obfdy4/1/).

Comment: @Leothelion i have also provided the link to the bootstrap page where and this code is working i have added a screenshot as well

Comment: @AniMenon i have edited my answer and added a screenshot as well 
pls think twice before down voting an answer

Comment: @Rasik Compare [yours](http://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/vSTLU/1802/) and [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/ani1/14obfdy4/2/). Whats wrong?
+1 once I get it.

Comment: @AniMenon the external resources ?

Comment: @Rasik, please check what we are discussing rather then saying who dv. Can't you provide why his link is not working? its simple but you are not mention that line in your answer..

Comment: @Leothelion Ani Menon comment shows that the only diff between our code is the api's

Comment: Well then i think you are not getting the point.leave it.. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Add data-placement attribute

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

Here is the bootstrap documentation for Tooltip

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips